# UIScrollview subviews not recognizing pan gesture after zooming

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiscrollview

I have a scrollview to which I have added an image view as a subview. The contentsize of the scrollview is same as the size of the imageview (width and height). There are two buttons outside the scrollview. When I click on either on them, a small rectangle view is added as a subview to the imageview. This rectangle view can be dragged anywhere on the imageview by the user after it has been added.

This works fine until I pinch to zoom the scrollview. In the viewForZoomingInScrollView: method, I return the imageview and the zooming works fine. But in the zoomed view when I try to drag around the rectangle view, it does not move. It does not recognize the pan gestures any more. Any idea why this is happening?

This Dragable view is too small and I have to change its position so I am zomming scrollview to touchable view.

Comment: what about gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer: ?

Comment: Thanks Mejdi, I have tried it but still not works...

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do this:
Inform the delegate when the zoom is finished by `calling:scrollViewDidEndZooming:withView:atScale:` 
in this method you update the parent view of the view where the rectangle can move or may be something else.....but you have to update something in this method....please put your specific code where the problem is.